# FileNotFoundError when running `npm run check` from `chromium/src/third_party/devtools-frontend/src`

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chromium

Here's the stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "third_party/node/node.py", line 58, in <module>
    RunNode(args, output)
  File "third_party/node/node.py", line 35, in RunNode
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
  File "/Users/alanhape/Library/Caches/.vpython-root/store/cpython+hiv3ibpot3sh9k38ig80e8uvk4/contents/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Users/alanhape/Library/Caches/.vpython-root/store/cpython+hiv3ibpot3sh9k38ig80e8uvk4/contents/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'third_party/node/mac/node-darwin-arm64/bin/node'
```

I'm trying to develop on a freshly checked out Chromium repo. Everything builds after following [this recommended guide](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/mac_build_instructions.md#Get-the-code).

But, when I navigate to the devtools-frontend repository (`chromium/src/third_party/devtools-frontend/src`) and run the package.json script `check` (`npm run check`), I get an error having to do with the file not being found. It looks like it's because the node-darwin-arm64 binaries havent been unpacked (?). What exists currently is `third_party/node/mac/node-darwin-arm64.tar.gz.sha1`.

I'm feeling like I'm missing some piece of information to set up my development environment, but I don't know what.

Comment: Why are you trying to run it? The third party deps `devtools-frontend` is used by Chromium and it's build system will handle building and integrating it with Chromium. Also, what are you trying to do by manually running it?

Comment: Did you run `gclient sync` after checking out the source code from Chromium? It will download all the third-party dependencies needed for Chromium to compile.

Comment: @Asesh, thanks for the response. I'm simply trying to hack on the devtools-frontend. Purely for fun, and learning purposes.

Comment: @Asesh I did run `gclient sync`. Chromium itself builds without a hitch, but somehow I don't think it recursively builds the sub-repos (`devtools-frontend` specifically), because when I  add some code that is intended to cause a TypeScript compile-time error, no errors appear. That is what led me to `cd` to `devtools-frontend/src` to try and run some of the npm scripts there. But, nothing runs because of the python errors

Comment: Okay I just re-ran `gclient sync` and I'm able to run `npm` scripts now.

The only thing that doesn't work is running `gn gen out/Default` due some path issues

`ERROR at //scripts/build/ninja/vars.gni:5:1: Unable to load "/Users/me/chromium/src/third_party/devtools-frontend/src/build/config/devtools.gni".`